# Dua objekto rekta post «kompare al» kaj simile

Tags: prepositions, accusative, adverbs

Post vortoj, kiel «anstataŭ» kaj «ol», substantivo povas esti akuzativigita se ĝi estas dua/alia objekto rekta (mi ne konas la nomon realan). Ekzemple...

> Mi volas tiun anstataŭ tiun!
> Mi volus tiun pli ol tiun!

Sed kio pri la okazo de «kompare al» kaj simile (parenteze, ĉu anstataŭe "similaj"?)?

> Kion signifas diri tion kompare al tion?

Tio estas, kvazaŭ estas implicita dua "diri" antaŭ la dua "tion". Normale, vorto akuzativigita ne povas esti post «al». Ĉu tia akuzativigo estas malĝusta? Ĉu la verbo ne estas forlasebla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La vorto post la prepozicio "anstataŭ" estas en la nominativo aŭ en la akuzativo depende de la rolo de la vorto. Traktu la ekzemplon:

- Petro batis Paŭlo**n** anstataŭ Vilhelmo : eble Vilhelmo intencis bati Paŭlon, sed li ne batis
- Petro batis Paŭlo**n** anstataŭ Vilhelmo**n**: eble Petro intencis bati Vilhelmon, sed li batis Paŭlon

Forlaso de la verbo "bati" el la esprimo "anstataŭ bati Vilhelmon" estas escepto, kiu temas nur pri la preposizio "anstataŭ". Rigardu la [rimarkon](https://vortaro.net/#anstata%C5%AD_kdc) en PIV.

Kie vi trovis la ekzemplon kun "kompare"? La ekzemplo estas malĝusta pro la kialo, kiun vi mem diris: post la prepozicio "al" oni neniam uzas la akuzativon. Miakomprene oni povas diri ambaŭmaniere:

- Kion signifas diri tion kompare al diri tion?
- Kion signifas diri tion kompare al tio?

La vorto "ol" estas konjunkcio, kiu ne efikas, ĉu sekvas nominativo aŭ akuzativo. Do

- Mi volus tiun pli ol tiun!

estas ĝusta, ĉar "tiu" estas rekta objekto al la verbo "voli".

Answer (score 1):

`ol` estas konjunkcio.

```
Mi volas tiun anstataŭ tiun! = Mi volas tiun anstataŭ ol mi volas tiun!
Mi volus tiun pli ol tiun! = Mi volus tiun pli ol ke mi volas tiun!
```

Jes `ol` komparas, sed tio estas duaranga. Precipe subfrazo estas ellasata. Kaj pro tio eble venas akuzativo.

```
Kion signifas diri tion kompare al tion? *** erare
Kion signifas diri tion kompare al tio?
```